# Output results of spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, output, spark-submit

I'm beginner in spark and scala programing, I tried running example with spark-submit  in local mode, it's run complete without any error or other message but i can't see any output result in consul or spark history web UI .Where and how can I see the results of my program in spark-submit?

This is a command that I run on spark

```
spark-submit --master local[*] --conf spark.history.fs.logDirectory=/tmp  /spark-events --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true  --conf   spark.eventLog.dir=/tmp/spark-events --conf spark.history.ui.port=18080 --class com.intel.analytics.bigdl.models.autoencoder.Train dist/lib/bigdl-0.5.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -f /opt/work/mnist  -b 8
```

and this is  a screenshot from end of run program

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also locate your `spark-defaults.conf` (or `spark-defaults.conf.template` and copy it to `spark-defaults.conf`)

Create a logging dir (like `/tmp/spark-events/`)

Add these 2 lines:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir               file:///tmp/spark-events/
```

And run `sbin/start-history-server.sh`

To make all jobs run by `spark-submit` log to event dir and overviews available in History Server (http://localhost:18080/) => Web UI, without keeping your spark job running

More info: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html

PS: On mac via homebrew this is all in the subdirs `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/[version]/libexec/`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this `while(true) Thread.sleep(1000)` in your code, to keep the server running then check the sparks task in the browser. Normally you should see your application running.

Answer (score 0):

thank a lot for your answer, I already made these settings in the spark-submit command using "--conf" and I can see web UI history  with "spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.history.HistoryServer" but I don't have access  to "start-history-server.sh" .I see tasks and jobs completed in history web UI ,I checked all the tabs (jobs,stages,storage, executors) and not found the output results nowhere
.can you explain to me where are the results in history web UI or even consul?(My goal is numerical results as the output of  the dataset accepted in the spark-submit command)

[screenshot from web UI history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsPSs.jpg)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To get the output from spark-submit, you can add below command in your code.scala file which we create and save in src/main/scala location before running sbt package command.

code.scala contents ->
........
........

result.saveAsTextFile("file:///home/centos/project")

Now, you should run "sbt package" command followed by "spark-submit". It will create project folder at your given location. This folder will contain two files: part-00000 and _SUCCESS. You can check your output in file -> part-00000